# Converting WriteableBitmap to Bitmap for use in EmguCV

Tags: c#, bitmap, kinect, emgucv, writeablebitmap

In my code, I'm receiving WriteableBitmaps from a byte array (in turn from a Kinect) and I'd like to turn them into bitmaps for use with EmguCV. Currently this is the code I have:

```
                // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

                // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
                this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                    new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                    this.colorPixels,
                    this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel,
                    0);

                    BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(colorBitmap));
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                    encoder.Save(ms);
                    Bitmap b=new Bitmap(ms);

                    Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, Byte>(b);
                    img = img.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(200), new Gray(255));
```

I got the bottom half of the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334110/how-to-convert-writeablebitmap-in-rgb24-pixel-format-into-a-emgucv-imagebgr-by).The code compiles and everything, but hangs when I'm trying to run the program (it's supposed to perform some operations on the image and then convert it back to a format that can be presented as an image.) Pausing my code and then using IntelliTrace in VS 2013, I get the following Exception  at `Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, Byte>(b);` "A System.ArgumentException was thrown: URI formats are not supported." Using alternate code, from where I go directly from byte to bitmap gives me the same error. ([Code can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730373/byte-array-to-bitmap-image))

Anyone got tips on how to resolve this error, or alternate ways of casting to bitmap? I'm a newbie with C# & EmguCV and I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all the code is fine. I'm not too sure on the technical details of the error, but the error is received when trying to write a Gray16 image in the WriteableBitmap (which is to be transformed into a Emgu Image.) Bgr565 or other formats are supported and I believe Gray16 wasn't fully implemented by MS. If doing a WinForms application, Format16bppGray will also give the same error.

I resolved to using a Gray Emgu image while writing the Bitmap as a Bgr555, which is a lot more noisy, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The exception with "URI formats are not supported" had nothing to do with the bitmap but with loading needed opencv dlls. I just copied the x86 and x64 folders including opencv_core290.dll and others to my executable directory.

Comment: It's actually a blanket error statement thrown for many different error. For my case it was the bitmap format, but it also occurs for incorrect dll loading, such as in your case.